# Js replace text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Просьба, подсказать, как корректно заменить `text` в данной структуре:

```
    <div class="card-footer">
        <div id="last_update" class="stats">
            <i class="material-icons">access_time</I>
                Sun Aug 15 2021 23:43:00 GMT+0400 (+04)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Соответсвенно, обновлять дату, мои попытки приводят к тому что, дата заменяется вместе с иконкой или добавляется в конец

Comment: По хорошему дату надо обернуть в `span`, иначе придется удалять все `Node#text`, которых после `<i>` может быть великое множество.

Comment: Чисто в теории можете попробовать выцепить текстовую ноду `document.querySelector('#last_update').lastChild.data = 'text'`, но крайне не советую, лучше в `span` обернуть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нет возможности добиться лучшей разметки, можно попробовать так:

```js
const textNode = document.querySelector('#last_update > i').nextSibling;

setInterval(() => {
  textNode.textContent = ` ${new Date()}`;
}, 1000)
```

```html
<div class="card-footer">
  <div id="last_update" class="stats">
    <i class="material-icons">access_time</i>
    Sun Aug 15 2021 23:43:00 GMT+0400 (+04)
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: теоретически, возможно в зависимости от браузера, после иконки  может оказаться несколько текстовых нод

Comment: @Grundy Тогда, наверное, нужно нормализовать их или перебирать и искать нужный текст. Если автор вопроса это допускает, пусть даст знать, что нужно переработать ответ.

Comment: Либо можно попробовать [нормализовать](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/normalize) контейнер.

Comment: @Grundy А нормализация всего родителя не влияет на дочерние элементы, не пересоздаёт их, как `innerHTML`?